# Json Object Deserialization

Tags: json, deserialization, flexjson

I want to deserialize the following JSON object to Java Object (Location Class) :

```json
{
  "city": "TEST",
  "country": "TEST",
  "latitude": "1",
  "longitude": "1",
  "name": "TEST",
  "postalCode": "362001",
  "street": "TEST",
  "organization": 3
}
```

My Java Class is :

```java
public class Location {
    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_location__organization")
    private Organization organization;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private boolean disabled;

    private String street;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public static List<Location> findAllLocationsOrderedByName()
    {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Location o ORDER BY name ASC", Location.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

And, Organization Class is :

```java
public class Organization {
    String name
}
```

I got following error when trying to deserialize:

```
flexjson.JsonNumber cannot be cast to java.util.Map
flexjson.factories.BeanObjectFactory.instantiate(BeanObjectFactory.java:17)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:95)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bindIntoObject(ObjectBinder.java:149)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:95)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:74)
flexjson.JSONDeserializer.deserialize(JSONDeserializer.java:158)
flexjson.factories.ClassLocatorObjectFactory.instantiate(ClassLocatorObjectFactory.java:38)
```

I use following code (using Flex JSON) for deserializing :

```java
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;
    
public static Location Location.fromJsonToLocation(String json) {
    System.out.println(json);
    return new JSONDeserializer<Location>()
        .use(null, Location.class).deserialize(json);
}
```

Comment: So? What's the question?

Comment: I want to Deserialize that Json Object in to Java Class.. when i tried i got following error 

flexjson.JsonNumber cannot be cast to java.util.Map
flexjson.factories.BeanObjectFactory.instantiate(BeanObjectFactory.java:17)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:95)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bindIntoObject(ObjectBinder.java:149)
flexjson.factories.ClassLocatorObjectFactory.instantiate(ClassLocatorObjectFactory.java:38)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:95)
flexjson.ObjectBinder.bind(ObjectBinder.java:74)
flexjson.JSONDeserializer.deserialize(JSONDeserializer.java:158)

Comment: Please update the question with this error.  Also please add what tool are you using to parse JSON.

Comment: Don't you think it should have been relevant to show us what you did not just what you want? In the question not in cumbersome and hard to read comments would be much better.

Comment: Please add the code you have used to parse JSON in the question.

Comment: public static Location Location.fromJsonToLocation(String json) {
     System.out.println(json);
        return new JSONDeserializer<Location>()
        .use(null, Location.class).deserialize(json);
    }

Comment: Please update it in the post not in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at organization value in Json. It's integer value but in Java object is Organization

Comment: So,what i need to pass there?
Should i pass this json object
{
  "city": "TEST",
  "country": "TEST",
  "latitude": "1",
  "longitude": "1",
  "name": "TEST",
  "postalCode": "362001",
  "street": "TEST",
  "organization": {"id" : 3 , "name" : "TEST"}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper to convert your json data to corresponding Object by using the following snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Location location= mapper.readValue(jsonData, Location.class);
```

Comment: @Devloper do you see any exception or any error message??